# How can i use "contains" in Freemaker code?

Tags: freemarker, contains

how can i use "contains" to check value of $?
I need to make a code that will print some text when $ contains some:

```
<#if orderItem.sku?contains("Flow")> 
1 https://flowsportstech.ru/ 
</#if>
```

Is it correct? It's not working thou...
Thank you!

Comment: `contains` exists since FreeMarker 2.3.1, if your version is ok, make sure sku is String

Comment: Hello! Thank you, what you mean sku is string? It's just an artical number in a order page...

Comment: Please always include the error message in your question, or if there's no error, then what happens instead of what you expect.

Comment: Nothing happens (( Just not text message appears. So it can be error in syntax. Is it correct? Syntax?